# How to query using a range and match under a must clause?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to pull data for the last 24 hours given a value that must match a field. I have written queries to match the value of the field and to query for the last 24 hours but I can't figure out how to combine them.

Query for the last 24h:

```
{
  "_source": ["instance_name", "@timestamp"], 
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "sampletime": {
        "gte": "now-24h",
        "lte": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query to match field:

```
{
  "_source": ["instance_name", "@timestamp"], 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "instance_name": "value_to_search"
    }
  }
}
```

Attempt to combine both:

```
{
  "_source": ["instance_name", "@timestamp"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "match": {
          "instance_name": "value"
        },
        "range": {
          "sampletime": {
            "gte": "now-24h",
            "lte": "now"
            }
          }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can combine these? Also can multiple values under the same field be targeted.

`instance_name == x || instance_name == y || instance_name == z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is very close.  The formatting around the `range` query is slightly off.

Here is the corrected sample:

```
{
  "_source": ["instance_name", "@timestamp"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "instance_name": "value"
          }
        },
        {
        "range": {
          "sampletime": {
            "gte": "now-24h",
            "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

On your second question, the `or` operator will be used by default for all match queries.

For example, the `FIELD` will match all hits with `a or b or c`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "FIELD": "a b c"
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about the full options for Match queries in the 
[official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)